# sorting a list keeping one entry from each duplicated line

Tags: command-line

ive have a list of films which i down load daily and comes in the following format

```
act-of-valor-2012
act-of-valor-2012
the-possession-2012
the-possession-2012
american-crude-2008
american-crude-2008
when-strangers-appear-2001
like-father-like-son-2005
like-father-like-son-2005
get-him-to-the-greek-2010
get-him-to-the-greek-2010
wall-street-money-never-sleeps-2010
wall-street-money-never-sleeps-2010
christmas-evil-1980
days-of-glory-1944
```

I need to keep this in the same order but delete dupl.icate lines so it becomes

```
act-of-valor-2012
the-possession-2012
american-crude-2008
when-strangers-appear-2001
like-father-like-son-2005
get-him-to-the-greek-2010
wall-street-money-never-sleeps-2010
christmas-evil-1980
days-of-glory-1944
```

sort changes the order any one have any ideas how i can accomplish this ?

THanks

Comment: What should happen if an item repeats again further down the list? Should we delete or keep it? Or should we assume all the duplicates will always be on adjacent lines?

Answer (score 6):

You want the `uniq` command.

From `man uniq`:

```
 Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

       With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence.
```

Use it as follows:

`uniq movies.txt`

Output as desired.

Comment: can't check man page right now, but i think `sort` has `-u` flag, for unique sort. Maybe that'd be useful

Comment: But `sort` also, eh, sorts. Which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Noticed that OP mentioned `sort` but didn't notice he wants to preserve list order as is

Comment: Note that uniq will not remove lines that are not adjacent to each other... all of the duplicates in the example in the question were adjacent, though it's not clear whether this will always be the case.

Answer (score 4):

AWK version:

```
awk '{array[i++]=$0}END{for(j=0;j<=i;j++) if(array[j] != array[j-1]){print array[j]}  }' movies.txt
```

Basically , what it does is read data into array and print out only those line that don't have previous line as duplicate.

Shorter way would be like shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193331/85039):

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' movies.txt                                                     
act-of-valor-2012
the-possession-2012
american-crude-2008
when-strangers-appear-2001
like-father-like-son-2005
get-him-to-the-greek-2010
wall-street-money-never-sleeps-2010
christmas-evil-1980
days-of-glory-1944
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help Sergs solution did the trick much appreciates